# Rails + SQLite3: Search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, sqlite

I'm currently building an e-commerce website that's going to be backed by a SQLite3 database. I'm looking for a way to do an in-browser search, with the results being links to products that match the search query. I've got no idea where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would highly suggest using MySQL or Postgresql instead of SQLite. SQLite is great for development, but afaik not ment for production deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? If you have enough products that you need search, use a database that will grow with you. SQLite is more for development and small/low-traffic applications. For example, Google Chrome uses it to store your history.

For very basic search, SQL-based finding is okay. You can do

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE "%query%" LIMIT 10;
```

…fairly easily, and relatively quickly (especially since you're using an index on that column, right?).

For more advanced or high-performance search with conditions, partial matches and searching across tables, you can use [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or another third-party search-specific application.

Comment: Just to add to what @coryward said, there is a gem called ferret [link]http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac/ for search too

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I'll look for a different database solution.